# List of floats trated as NoneType

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I am having some trouble while working with list. I just want a very smple thing just take a number from a list in a function and multiply this number for another one in the main. Actually it works, i mean that the number taken from the list is the right one but when i multiply it for the number in the main, python makes exception saying that i cannot multiply 'float' with 'Nonetype'. So basically Python says tha my actually floats in the list are notype. Any suggestions?

Sorry i am new here. not sure where to put the code, so i am putting it here:

```
def findTime(time):

    day = 86400
    seconds = time % day
    f = [0.005, 0.03, 0.08, 0.15, 0.3, 0.7, 1, 0.8, 0.65, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3]
    perc = np.array(f, float)
    step = 2*60*60 # 2hours step
    phase_di_prima = -1
    i = 0
    for phase in range(0,day, step):
        #print("phase", phase)
        i = 0
        if seconds<phase and seconds>phase_di_prima:
            percentuale = perc[i]
            print("for arrival = "+ str(seconds)+ " perc = "+ str(percentuale))
            return percentuale.astype(float)
        phase_di_prima = phase
        i += 1


main


time_arrival = env.now + time_shift


    while True:
        perc = findTime(time_arrival)
        arrival_rate *= perc <----- error here
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Comment: python 2 or 3??

Comment: Your variables are defined in the function only. Main is somehow messed.

Comment: Assuming 1 would need to be 1.0 in "f"?

Answer (score 0):

Define `arrival_rate`:

```
arrival_rate = 1.0
while True:
    perc = findTime(time_arrival)
    arrival_rate *= perc
```